# Windows IIS - Redirect to local port

Tags: iis

I serve static files of my webapp over Port 443, 80 (HTTP standard ports). Furthermore only Port 443 and 80 are rachable from outside.

On the server there is running a local server on port 5000 serving a REST API.

Workflow:

- user requests webapp via /index.html
- user receives webapp
- webapp performs an asynchronous request to the rest api via /api/webservicename
- IIS should now redirect this request to something like localhost:5000/webservicename

I installed already URL Rewrite Extensionn for IIS and tried some rewriting rules, but it doesn't work. Is it possible to do this with this extension? If so, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the Advanced Request Routing (ARR) extension to rewrite to a different site. It can be found here: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing